# PHP Time Validator to accept 1 digit number for hour and minutes

Tags: php, validation, time

So I have made this validator in PHP that validates if time provided is 24hr format:

```
$cols = [
        'time'  => $val['time'],
];

$validator = Validator::make($cols, 
           [
            'time' => ['required','regex:/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/'],
           ],
           [
            'time.required' => 'Start time is a required field.',
            'time.regex'    => 'Start time is not a valid 24hr format.',
          ],
);
```

So this successfully validates if time format is `hh:mm`, but how can I make it accept values in `h:mm` or `h:m` or `hh:m` formats like `9:00`, `9:1`, `10:1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making the first digit character class `[]` grouping optional with `?`, you should be able to support omitting it.

```
'time' => ['required','regex:/^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]$/'],
// ------------------------------------------^------------^------

$pattern = '/^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]$/';
foreach (['12:24','9:24','9:5','12:5','23:00','22:9'] as $time) {
  var_dump((bool)preg_match($pattern, $time));
}
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)

// non-matching
foreach (['99:22','99:0','0:99'] as $invalid) {
  var_dump((bool)preg_match($pattern, $invalid));
}
// bool(false)
// bool(false)
// bool(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. But why is it that it's not accepting `20:00` to `23:00` and `0:00` to `2:00`. It's the time that didn't pass my test so far :)

Comment: Hold on, I'll sort it out. I am not seeing problems with 0:00-2:00 by the way, but I do see problems with 20:00-23:00.

Comment: The additional hours non capturing `(?:...)` turned out to be unnecessary and problematic

Answer (score 1):

You can also this pattern:

```
/^(?:2[0-3]|([01])?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

It has the same result with @Michael

Cheers